# .htaccess with 301 redirect for search engines

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my .htaccess file on domain-a.com, which should do a 301 redirect for only search engines to domain-b.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain-a.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} msnbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Slurp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.domain-b.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I think I missed something somewhere because this causes the domain to do crazy stuff. The problem is I get in sort of a loop with the domain names, and this results in a 404.

For testing I use the user agent switching add-on in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)domain-a\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot|msnbot|Slurp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-b.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```